# How to understan equilibrium in Statistical Mechanics' angle?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, equilibrium

I'm just learning Statistical Mechanics via *Entorpy, Order Paraments, and Complexity* written by James P. Sethna and be stucked here in Section 3.3. I didn't understand the sentense below (also highlighted in the figure):

> Statistical Mechanics insists that the distribution of heat between the two bodies is determined by the microcanonical assumption that all possible states of fixed total energy for the two bodies are equally likely.

Specificly, what does **distribution of heat** mean? It seems that the writer never gives a definition of heat in the previous part, please indicate me in case I just missed the definition.

Also, is it an axiom that the microcanonical assumption here has determined a distribution of heat, or is it derived afterwards and I should just take it for granted now? It might be a tiny and subtle question but I can't think through it.

Thanks for reading till here patiently. I didn't speak English well and feel sorry if the question disturbs you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> "Statistical Mechanics insists that the distribution of heat between
>   the two bodies is determined by the microcanonical assumption that all
>   possible states of fixed total energy for the two bodies are equally
>   likely"

First let me say I am not conversant in statistical thermodynamics. But from the standpoint of macro thermodynamics it seems that Sethna is using the term heat when it should be internal energy. In macro thermodynamics heat is defined as energy transfer between bodies due solely to a temperature difference between the bodies. Bodies do not "contain" heat. The proper term is *internal energy*. To me the quote seems to imply that the two bodies contain heat.

Perhaps "heat" means something different in statistical thermodynamics, or I don't fully understand the quote.

I'd like to hear what someone conversant in statistical thermodynamics has to say.

Anyway, for what it's worth, hope this helps.

Comment: I totally agree with you. Sethna is clearly (mis)using the term heat to indicate internal energy (sometimes referred to as "thermal energy").

Comment: @GiorgioP Thanks for the support. I've been following your work and have been impressed.

Answer (score 0):

I think that by "*distribution of heat*" the author just refers to the energy flow that goes from the hot body to the cold one.

The microcanonical assumption here is used to look for conditions that the number of microstates should follow in equilibrium. In particular, it can be readily shown (see Pathria's Statistical Mechanics) that $\partial_{E_1}ln(\Omega(E_1))=\partial_{E_2}ln(\Omega(E_2))$. By comparing with the zeroth law of thermodynamics (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeroth_law_of_thermodynamics) it is possible to link the quantity $\partial_{E}ln\Omega(E)$ with the inverse of the temperature and indeed state that there must be an energy flow (this "distribution of heat") that drives the system to thermal equilibrium.